# Gui Freeze after pressing a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I have a problem that my whole gui freezes when I try to press button level 1. my main problem is to set a new panel which is empty one for now.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Guibach extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel choosingPanel;
    private JPanel x;

    private JButton exit;

    private JButton but1;
    private JButton but2;
    private JButton but3;
    private JButton but4;
    private JButton but5;
    private JButton but6;
    private JButton but7;
    private JButton but8;
    private JButton but9;
    private JButton but10;

    public Guibach() {
        this.setSize(900, 900);
        this.setLayout(null);

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setSize(900, 900);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);

        x = new JPanel();
        x.setSize(900, 900);
        x.setBackground(Color.RED);
        x.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        choosingPanel = new JPanel();
        choosingPanel.setSize(900, 450);
        choosingPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        choosingPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        but1 = new JButton();
        but1.setText("Level 1");
        but1.setSize(10, 5);
        but1.setActionCommand("but1");
        but1.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but1);

        but2 = new JButton();
        but2.setText("Level 2");
        but2.setActionCommand("but2");
        but2.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but2);

        but3 = new JButton();
        but3.setText("Level 3");
        but3.setActionCommand("but3");
        but3.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but3);

        but4 = new JButton();
        but4.setText("Level 4");
        but4.setActionCommand("but4");
        but4.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but4);

        but5 = new JButton();
        but5.setText("Level 5");
        but5.setActionCommand("but5");
        but5.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but5);

        but6 = new JButton();
        but6.setText("Level 6");
        but6.setActionCommand("but6");
        but6.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but6);

        but7 = new JButton();
        but7.setText("Level 7");
        but7.setActionCommand("but7");
        but7.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but7);

        but8 = new JButton();
        but8.setText("Level 8");
        but8.setActionCommand("but8");
        but8.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but8);

        but9 = new JButton();
        but9.setText("Level 9");
        but9.setActionCommand("but9");
        but9.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but9);

        but10 = new JButton();
        but10.setText("Level 10");
        but10.setActionCommand("but10");
        but10.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(but10);

        exit = new JButton();
        exit.setText("Exit");
        exit.setActionCommand("exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        choosingPanel.add(exit);

        mainPanel.add(choosingPanel);
        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but1")) {
            choosingPanel.setVisible(false);
            mainPanel.removeAll();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(x);
            x.setVisible(true);
            revalidate();


        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but2")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but3")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but4")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but5")) {

        }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but6")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but7")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but8")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but9")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("but10")) {

        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("exit")) {
            WindowDestroyer myListener = new WindowDestroyer();
            this.addWindowListener(myListener);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Guibach();
    }

}
```

I need to clear all the things and place a new empty panel which is X in my code.

Comment: If you want to replace one panel (component) with another one, you should use the [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Another vote for `CardLayout`. On the other hand, you can make the current code work by adding `repaint()` after the revalidation (for the future, when you may want to add or remove components at run time).

Comment: Thanks guys really appreciated :")